# Qt - How to improve my contextmenu

Tags: qt

with help of visitors of this forum I have made a custom context menu in QListWidget. Now Im trying to solve a problem that the menu is showing up when the user have rightclicked on the widget but the mouse wasnt over any item. When this situation occurs I want the menu to not show up.. Ive been thinking about obvious condition - is the mouse over some item in the widget? But I dont know how to do this. 
thank you in advance for all the answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not show how you are currently creating your context menu, I will assume from the beginning...

1. Set your widget's [contextMenuPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) to [Qt::CustomContextMenu](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum)
2. Connect the widgets [customContextMenuRequested](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal to a slot that will show your custom menu
3. The slot will receive a QPoint in local widget coordinates. You can use this QPoint to find out which item is under that point with [QListWidget.itemAt(QPoint)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemAt). You can then validate that pointer. If it's a valid item, show your menu at that point (or some offset of it that suits you). A valid item means a non-null pointer.

Here is an example of what it looks like in PyQt. You can translate this to Qt

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.list.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.list.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.handleContext)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)

        self.list.addItems(["one", "two"])

    def handleContext(self, pos):
        item = self.list.itemAt(pos)
        if item is not None:
            menu = QtGui.QMenu("Context Menu", self)
            menu.addAction("FOO")
            ret = menu.exec_(self.list.mapToGlobal(pos))
```

In PyQt4, if the item at the given position is `None`, then it was an empty space. In Qt, it should be a null pointer.

Comment: I have it done just like you say. Function for creating contexmenu
    void MainWindow::contextMenuforNotesArea(const QPoint &pos){
        QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);
        ...
        contextMenu.exec(ui->notesWidget->mapToGlobal(pos));
    }

[link]http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/4735/nb1h.png
the big central widget is the listWidget connected to the function above
[link]http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/2599/nb2t.png
this is the problem, when user click on empty space in widget the item he clicked on before is still selected so contextmenu will show up for that item.

Comment: Did you actually check the item at the position before showing the popul or did you just blindly raise a popup? My answer says to check the position and see if the item is valid before popping up

Comment: Im sory I may messesd something with my English, but thats the question that how I can check whether the item is valid